# ng2-dnd wrong item getting dragged and dropped(multi sortable) after applying filter

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular2-services

I'm using angular 2 to implement multi-sortable d&d with the following package
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-dnd.

I'm able to drag and drop items from one container to other and vice versa.
However, when i filter and item and then try to drag wrong item is getting dragged and dropped into the other container(the one which generally applies that index and not the one which actually is there). This could be may be because the code uses sortableIndex

Here's the code:

```
<div>
 <h4>Groups</h4>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <div class="panel panel-warning">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            Available Groups
          </div>
          <div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="" placeholder="search" [(ngModel)]="name"/>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body" dnd-sortable-container [dropZones]="['boxers-zone']" [sortableData]="listBoxers">
            <ul class="list-group" >
              <li *ngFor="let item of listBoxers | DataFilterPipe: name; let i = index" class="list-group-item" dnd-sortable [sortableIndex]="i">{{item.name}}</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-5">
        <div class="panel panel-success">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            Selected Groups
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body" dnd-sortable-container [dropZones]="['boxers-zone']" [sortableData]="listTeamOne">
            <ul class="list-group" >
              <li *ngFor="let item of listTeamOne; let i = index" class="list-group-item" dnd-sortable [sortableIndex]="i">{{item.name}}</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>

listBoxers:Array<object> = [];
listTeamOne:Array<object> = [];

this.listBoxers= [{id:"1",name:"ABC"}, {id:"2", name:"erwxyz"},{id:"2", name:"sdaxyz"},{id:"3", name:"sdxyz"},{id:"4", name:"xyz"}]
```

Here's the screenshots:

[image]

[image]

As you can see in the second screenshot, even after filtering 'xyz', I tried to grad this item. Howver, wrong item got dragged and dropped(the one present at that index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `(ngModelChange)` instead of filter pipe `(DataFilterPipe)`. Then wrote a custom fuction for `(ngModelChange)`. That worked.